# DOMDocument - How to get all inner text except from style/script tags?

Tags: parsing, domdocument, domxpath

I spent so much time on a very simple thing and had to post here on StackOverflow

I want to get all inner text except the script/style tags

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$html = <<<EOD
<div>
        <script>var main=0</script>
        <div>
            <p>my</p>
            <script>var inner=0</script>
        </div>
        <p>text</p>
        only
</div>
EOD;

$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

echo $entries = $xpath->query('//*[not(self::script)]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

gives me

```
var main=0 my var inner=0 text only
```

and also tried

```
$entries = $xpath->query('//*[not(self::script)]');
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    if ($entry->tagName == 'style' || $entry->tagName == 'script') {
        continue;
    }
    echo preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $entry->nodeValue);
}
```

gives me

```
var main=0 my var inner=0 text only var main=0 my var inner=0 text only var main=0 my var inner=0 text only my var inner=0mytext
```

I tried several xpaths but it doesn't work

my desired output is `my text only`

I am a Scrapy developer and I do that easily in Scrapy, but having a bad time with PHP today

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PHP doesn't support xpath 2.0 (and, IIRC, neither does Scrapy), so the `name()` method which would have made it easy, isn't available...

The closest thing I can think of is the following, which should get you close enough (note that, because there is no `<style>` tag in your `$html`, I only focused on `<script>`):

```
$entries = $xpath->query('//*[not(./text()/parent::script)]/text()');
foreach ($entries as $entry) {

    echo trim($entry->textContent) . " ";
    
}
```

Output:

```
my    text only
```

Comment: How would I ignore the style tag as well?

Comment: @UmairAyub Not sure; as I mentioned in the answer, there is no `<style>` tag in your sample html, so I can't tell.